# Insert in relationship table after inserting record

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this classes and a WebApi method to POST the **Item**.

After inserting **Item** i want it to insert the inserted PK *ItemId* and given *CategoryId* into **CategoryItem**

```
  public partial class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Type { get; set; }
    }

  public partial class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Categoryitem
    {
        public int IdCategory { get; set; }
        public int IdItem { get; set; }

        public virtual Category IdCategoryNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual Item IdItemNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Item> PostItem(Item item)
        {
            _context.Item.Add(item);
            
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();

        }
```

How do i pass the IdCategory into POST method ? Do I need a *CategoryCollection* in **Item** class and pass *IdCategory* through **Item** member ?

What about the relationship table ? How do i insert the two Ids ?

Thank you

Comment: " given CategoryId " what does it  mean? who gives it to you? can you show the code?

Comment: selected in UI before requesting POST

Comment: And where  is it in your code? How are you going to save what you don't have?

Comment: It isn't, thats why i ask how do i POST it. Send it inside Item object (with collection) ? create another parameter in PostItem (Item item, int catid) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a viewmodel if you need to add several categories in the same time when you create an item, or if you only  assign one category when you create  an item you can just add CategoryId, but with attribute [NotMapped]

```
public partial class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
         ... another properties
        [NotMapped]
        public int? CategoryId{ get; set; }
    }
```

or fluent api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().Ignore(c => c.CategoryId);
```

you will have to bind this CategoryId to dropdown list in the view

and action

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Item> PostItem(Item item)
        {
            var categoryitem = new Categoryitem
            {
               IdItemNavigation=item,
              IdCategory = item.CategoryId
            };

            _context.Categoryitem.Add(categoryitem);
            
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(item);

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Serge, i'll try it. What about the many-to-many relationship ? How to i insert in that table (CategoryItem) after inserting in Item table ?

Comment: @xnotte This is many-to-many already since you are using an extra table.